# How to flush endpoint data after a user signs out? Node/React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using React.
I have an endpoint which serves data back to the user. My problem appears to be that when I sign out, which is just a simple

```
<a href="/"/>
```

I don't lose the data on the endpoint, so that when I sign in again, I have twice as much data showing because the previous data hasn't been flushed. Is this a problem that I should resolve in React or Node? What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush the data before you go to `/`. Add an `onClick` handler to the `<a>` tag and do the cleanup there.